# Comparing more than two populations

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, anova

I have a dataset of around 20 financial advisors and their customers. The customers have been divided into groups based on type of investment, as well as the size of their investment and whether the customer is a private person or holding company. The data is sorted in a table as illustrated below, with both value of investment and number of customers. The number of customers per advisor differ from approx. 30-300.

[image]

I would like to find if there are significant differences between advisors and what kind of customers they have in their portfolio. For example regarding the customers size and if possible, regarding the type of asset classes they have invested in.

I have so far thought of using ANOVA through regression, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, and precisely how it would be done.

Input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want o test each advisor against each other?

Comment: Yes, that was the intention. I am somewhat sceptical regarding how useful that information will be though, but I would like to give it a try.

Comment: Maybe start with visualization .... and maybe even clustering?